# Nginx + PHP on docker serving static files

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have two containers: nginx and php-fpm. The files are stored on the php-fpm container. There is no problem with serving PHP files, but I need to serve static files as well, and I have a problem with the location configuration.

No idea how to configure it correctly.

```
location /static/ {
    fastcgi_pass api:9000;
}
```

or I tried:

```
location /vendor/ {
    root api:9000/public/vendor/;
}
```

This is the config file:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
root /app/api/public;
index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location /static/ {
    fastcgi_pass api:9000;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass api:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot access files in another container. Best option would be to have the files available in the nginx container (if possible).

Comment: Thank you! this is part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @slauth mentioned, there is no way to access files to another container.

I decided to serve static images using PHP. Here is a good tutorial: https://grahamlikesto.codes/slim-php-how-to-serve-static-files-with-slim-php/

This is not the best solution. My app is a small app with little traffic, and serving assets is not a big deal, but you should change your architecture if you run this issue.